# Mac USB keyboard sometimes works, sometimes doesn't - how do I reset it?

Tags: mac, usb, keyboard

I have a MacBook Pro with an external generic USB keyboard / hub. The keyboard stopped working - usually. If I unplug it and plug it back in a few dozen times, the keyboard usually starts working again. It then continues working with no problems until I unplug it again. I have a USB mouse plugged into the keyboard's USB hub - this always works fine.

Any ideas? Is there a way I can force MacOS to re-initialize the USB device via software, without physically unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a Wacom tablet and it turned out to be a faulty cable in the tablet itself. You should try another keyboard and see what results you get.

Comment: That's what I'd try first, but if the cable is built in to the keyboard you'd be SOL. Try the keyboard on another computer and see if you have the same problems.

Comment: The keyboard has a built-in USB hub. I have a mouse plugged into the keyboard's hub, and it invariably works fine, leading me to believe that it's probably not a damaged cable.. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Oh, I've tried other keyboards - other keyboards work fine. My main question is how can I force OS X to re-scan or re-initialize its USB drivers via software?